# Ansible output in MySql Database

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have ansible playbook to perform updates on linux servers. This playbooks is working fine. I wanted to get output of this playbook and insert it to MySql Database. Below is my ansible playbook

```
---
- name: Running Updates on Amazon Linux 2
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: yes
  

  tasks:
    - name: Run yum update with exceptions
      become: yes
      yum:
        name: '*'
        state: latest
        exclude: "httpd*,nginx*,mod24_ssl,php*,mod_ssl,nodejs*,npm*,mod_ldap*,ansible*,jenkins*,puppet*,varnish*,log4j*,java*,mysql*,mod_security*,libssh2*"
      register: yum_update_output

    - name: Display updated packages
      debug:
        var: yum_update_output.changes

    - name: Parse JSON and Extract Relevant Information
      set_fact:
        extracted_changes: "{{ yum_update_output.changes }}"

    - name: Debug extracted_changes.updated
      debug:
        var: extracted_changes.updated


    - name: Store extracted changes in MySQL
      mysql_db:
        login_user: "username"
        login_password: "password"
        login_host: "host"
        login_port: 3306
        name: yum_update_data
        state: query
        with_together:
          - "{{ extracted_changes.updated | map(attribute=0) | list }}"
          - "{{ extracted_changes.updated | map(attribute=1) | list }}"
        loop_var: package_name, version
        query: >
          INSERT INTO yum_update_changes (package_name, version, update_time)
          VALUES ('{{ package_name }}', '{{ version }}', NOW())
```

And below is output for `extracted_changes.updated`

```
ok: [server1] => {
    "extracted_changes.updated": [
        [
            "libicu",
            "50.2-4.amzn2.0.1.x86_64 from amzn2-core"
        ],
        [
            "ecs-init",
            "1.74.1-1.amzn2.x86_64 from amzn2extra-ecs"
        ],
        [
            "iputils",
            "20180629-11.amzn2.1.20160308.x86_64 from amzn2-core"
        ],
        [
            "python-requests",
            "2.6.0-10.amzn2.0.1.noarch from amzn2-core"
        ],
        [
            "openldap",
            "2.4.44-25.amzn2.0.7.x86_64 from amzn2-core"
        ],
        [
            "python-ipaddress",
            "1.0.16-2.amzn2.0.2.noarch from amzn2-core"
        ],
        [
            "python3-pip",
            "20.2.2-1.amzn2.0.4.noarch from amzn2-core"
        ],
        [
            "libcap",
            "2.54-1.amzn2.0.2.x86_64 from amzn2-core"
        ],
        [
            "glib2",
            "2.56.1-9.amzn2.0.6.x86_64 from amzn2-core"
        ]
    ]
}
```

When tried to insert data in mysql it gives below error

```
{"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'package_name' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in 'updated-playbook.yml': line 30, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n    - name: Store extracted changes in MySQL\n      ^ here\n"}
```

I also tried with below approaches but still getting same error

```
- name: Store extracted changes in MySQL
      mysql_db:
        login_user: "username"
        login_password: "password"
        login_host: "host"
        login_port: 3306
        name: yum_update_data
        state: query
        loop: "{{ extracted_changes.updated }}"
        loop_var: package_info
        query: >
          INSERT INTO yum_update_changes (package_name, version, update_time)
          VALUES ('{{ package_info.0 }}', '{{ package_info.1 }}', NOW())
```

and

```
    - name: Store extracted changes in MySQL
      mysql_db:
        login_user: "username"
        login_password: "password"
        login_host: "host"
        login_port: 3306
        name: yum_update_data
        state: query
        query: >
          INSERT INTO yum_update_changes (package_name, version, update_time)
          VALUES ('{{ item.0 }}', '{{ item.1 }}', NOW())
        loop: "{{ extracted_changes.updated }}"
```

Can anyone please assist me in this?

Answer (score 0):

Too long code so posting here. Try this corrected version and see if it works for you

```
- name: Running Updates on Amazon Linux 2
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: yes

  tasks:
    - name: Run yum update with exceptions
      become: yes
      yum:
        name: '*'
        state: latest
        exclude: "httpd*,nginx*,mod24_ssl,php*,mod_ssl,nodejs*,npm*,mod_ldap*,ansible*,jenkins*,puppet*,varnish*,log4j*,java*,mysql*,mod_security*,libssh2*"
      register: yum_update_output

    - name: Store extracted changes in MySQL
      mysql_db:
        login_user: "username"
        login_password: "password"
        login_host: "host"
        login_port: 3306
        name: yum_update_data
        state: query
        loop: "{{ extracted_changes.updated }}"
        loop_var: package_info
        query: >
          INSERT INTO yum_update_changes (package_name, version, update_time)
          VALUES ('{{ package_info.0 }}', '{{ package_info.1 }}', NOW())
```

Comment: I tried that too, however it doesn't worked